# Installation of Yii2 on Heroku fails.

Tags: php, heroku, yii2, composer-php

Can't Install Yii2 on Heroku.

I'm trying to install Yii2-basic-application template on Heroku. 
But I'm facing dependency/composer issues.

The application runs perfectly on local machine, but while deploying to `heroku`, it throws
a ReflectionClass Error, (Class yii\debug\Module not found). This exception is about y[ii2-debug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug)module. 
I don't know anything about the internal workings of composer. 
I have run `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload` but no help.
The files actually exist on the server, which makes me think it might be a problem about class-mapping in composer related files.

Also, one reason could be a broken plugin yii2 uses for dependency management, called [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin), 
The Yii2 repo on Github also reports problems with this plugin ().

I would also appreciate alternate workarounds, as it is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Your Heroku app is running in production. Verify that `YII_ENV` is set.

```
heroku config:set YII_ENV=prod
```

Your yii2-debug is probably only in development. So it won't be installed in production.

`composer.json`

```
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
```

If you are running console commands during deployment, then you have to make sure you don't autoload or bootstrap the `debug` module.

`console.php`

```
'bootstrap' => YII_ENV == 'dev' ? ['log', 'gii'] : ['log'],
'modules' => YII_ENV == 'dev' ? [
  'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module'
] : [],
```

Also see [Can someone explain how Yii minimizing assets is supposed to work on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429928/can-someone-explain-how-yii-minimizing-assets-is-supposed-to-work-on-heroku)

If this doesn't help, can you include the console output during deploy?